# Escolher qual SELECT fazer a partir de uma tabela temporária

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma tabela temporária com `WITH` no **MS SQL Server** que, caso o valor de uma variável seja um, eu faço um `SELECT`, caso seja outro, faço outro `SELECT`. É possível? Tentei escrever algo com `CASE/ELSE`, não fica nenhum campo vermelho na query porém ao dar F5 retornou um erro.

Minha tabela:

```
DECLARE @tipo INT;
SET @tipo = 1; /* Esse valor será recebido do PHP, deixei 1 só como exemplo. */

WITH temp AS (
    SELECT id,descricao,tipo
    FROM Itens_Menu_Botao
    WHERE id_menu = 22
)

SELECT
    CASE WHEN @tipo = 1 THEN (
        SELECT * FROM temp
    ) ELSE (
        SELECT T.id FROM temp T INNER JOIN Itens_Grupo IG ON T.id = IG.id_menu
    ) END;
```

O erro (sim está em português mesmo):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por favor alguém tem alguma sugestão melhor?

Comment: Acho que no SQL Server você teria que montar uma query dinâmica para executar com o Exec, Execute ou a procedure SP_ExecuteSQL. Ou talvez montar a query na aplicação

Answer (score 0):

No seu caso dá pra usar `IF..ELSE`:

```
DECLARE @tipo INT = 1; /* Esse valor será recebido do PHP, deixei 1 só como exemplo. */

IF @tipo = 1
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM (SELECT id,descricao,tipo
          FROM Itens_Menu_Botao
          WHERE id_menu = 22);
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT T.id 
    FROM (SELECT id,descricao,tipo
          FROM Itens_Menu_Botao
          WHERE id_menu = 22) T 
    INNER JOIN Itens_Grupo IG ON T.id = IG.id_menu;
END
```

Mas não dá para usar a CTE, por isso repeti sua consulta.

Uma solução para isso é transformar essa CTE em view:

```
CREATE VIEW vwItemMenuBotao AS
SELECT id,descricao,tipo
FROM Itens_Menu_Botao
GO

DECLARE @tipo INT = 1; /* Esse valor será recebido do PHP, deixei 1 só como exemplo. */

IF @tipo = 1
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM vwItemMenuBotao
    WHERE id_menu = 22;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT T.id 
    FROM vwItemMenuBotao T 
    INNER JOIN Itens_Grupo IG ON T.id = IG.id_menu
    WHERE T.id_menu = 22;
END
```

**Mas a minha opinião sobre isso: essa complexidade pode estar no seu código PHP e não em uma quase *procedure* no SQL Server.**